# Azure SQL stored procedure ridiculously slow called from C#

Tags: c#, sql, performance, azure, stored-procedures

**Summary**:

We have two identical databases, one on a local server, one on Azure.

We have a C# system that accesses these databases, calling stored procedures.

The stored procedures are running very, very slowly when called from the C# system to the Azure database. They're running fine from C# to the local server, and from SSMS to both the Azure and the local databases.

As an example, calling the stored procedure 'usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select'

Local database, SSMS : 1 second

Local database, C# : 1 second

Azure database, SSMS : 1 second

Azure database, C# : **17 minutes**

This is happening on multiple stored procedures, I'm just using usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select as an example, to test solutions and to trace the execution plan.

I've ruled out ARITHABORT (the usual suspect), and it seems that running usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select in SSMS and from the C# system generate a functionally identical execution plan.

**Details**:

We write a very large C# system, which accesses SQL Server databases.

Currently all our clients host their own databases locally on their own servers, however we are looking into the option of hosting the databases on Azure. So I set up some small Azure test databases, ironed out the kinks, and got an Azure-hosted system going.

Then I copied one of our client's databases up, to compare performance hosted locally vs hosted on Azure.

The actual client database is performing unusably badly on Azure!

The first screen calls a stored procedure 'usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select'

Connection to the database on their server:-

In SSMS, calling the stored procedure (below) returns the values in about 1 second

```
EXEC usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select @MaxRecord = 100, @SearchType = 'CUR'
```

In our C# program, calling the stored procedure returns the values in about 1 second

Connection to the database on Azure:-

In SSMS, calling the stored procedure returns the values in about 1 second

In our C# program, calling the stored procedure returns the values in about **17 minutes**!

Fast in SSMS and slow from C# usually means ARITHABORT, so I turned it on at the start of the stored procedure :

```
SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

That didn't make any difference, so I updated it to convert the passed parameters to local variables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select]
     (@MAXRECORD INT,
      @SEARCHTYPE VARCHAR(3))
AS
BEGIN
    SET ARITHABORT ON; 

    DECLARE @MAXRECORD_Var INT = @MAXRECORD
    DECLARE @SEARCHTYPE_Var VARCHAR(3) = @SEARCHTYPE

    ... (Updated all references to @MAXRECORD and @SEARCHTYPE to @MAXRECORD_Var and @SEARCHTYPE_Var)

END
```

Still no joy, so I got the Execution Plan details for both:-

```
select o.object_id, s.plan_handle, h.query_plan 
from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s on o.object_id = s.object_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) h
where o.object_id = object_id('usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select')
```

And just to check, I reloaded the screen in the C# program, and checked the running query:-

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time,
req.plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

It is definitely using one of the two execution plans returned above.

So, check the settings for the Execution Plans

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes (0x05002D00D1A1EA5510E66E783602000001);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes (0x05002D00D1A1EA55E0FC6E783602000001);
```

[image: Compare Settings]

Set_Options is **4345** for both, so they're definitely both using ARITHABORT.

The only differences are the localisation bits: Language and Date Format. The Azure database is stuck in American, can't seem to change that, while the C# program forces it to British.

I tried the C# program without forcing it to British, and still got the same issue. It also used exactly the same Execution Plan, so clearly localisation doesn't affect that.

So, I called up the info on the Execution Plans:-

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan (0x05002D00D1A1EA5510E66E783602000001);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan (0x05002D00D1A1EA55E0FC6E783602000001);
```

Saved them both, and compared the results:-

[image: Compare Execution Plans]

The two columns far left show the overall comparison: yellow being different, white being the same.
As you can see, the two Execution Plans are almost identical, just with a handful of differences at the top.

The first differences can be seen in the above screenshot: the 'StatementCompId' is one higher in the SSMS (left) pane than the C# (right) pane. Google doesn't want to tell me what **StatementCompId** is, but given they're in sequence I'm guessing it's the order to do them in, and the SSMS is one higher because the EXEC command that called the SP counts as one.

For ease, I've compiled all the remaining differences into a single screenshot:-

[image: Compare Execution Plans]

Compile times and CPU usages, free memory, and a couple more 'StatementCompId'

So, the two Execution Plans are functionally identical, with identical settings (except localisation which doesn't seem to have an effect).

So why does it take around 17 minutes calling the Azure SP from C# compared to around 1 second calling the Azure SP from SSMS or the local SP from the locally-hosted database either way?

The Stored Procedure itself is just a SELECT FROM, with a few LEFT JOINs to other tables, nothing fancy and it's never given us any trouble on locally-hosted databases.

```
SELECT TOP (@MAXRECORD_Var) <FieldList>
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT <FieldList>
    FROM <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK) ON <Link>
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK) ON <Link>
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK) ON <Link>
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK) ON <Link>
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> WITH (NOLOCK) ON <Link>
    WHERE (
        <Conditions>
    ) AS Base
ORDER BY <FieldName>
```

**Edit: Some Progress**

I tried several things that came up from Googling:-

1) WITH RECOMPILE

I tried adding this to the Stored Procedure, didn't make any difference

2) OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@MAXRECORD_Var UNKNOWN, @SEARCHTYPE_Var UNKNOWN))

I tried adding this to the Stored Procedure, didn't make any difference

3) Explicitly setting all options

This one made a noticeable (but still far too small) difference!

I wrote a query to tell me the current options

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS
PRINT @options
PRINT 'SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK ' + CASE WHEN ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ' + CASE WHEN ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT ' + CASE WHEN ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS ' + CASE WHEN ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_PADDING ' + CASE WHEN ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULLS ' + CASE WHEN ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ARITHABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ARITHIGNORE ' + CASE WHEN ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ' + CASE WHEN ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT ' + CASE WHEN ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ' + CASE WHEN ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF ' + CASE WHEN ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ' + CASE WHEN ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET XACT_ABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
```

This produced a set of SET statements, and the current Options value

```
5496
SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK OFF;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET ARITHIGNORE OFF;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON;
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF OFF;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

**Note**: Running SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK OFF; throws an error, so I commented that one out.

```
'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' is not a recognized SET option.
```

Adding this to the start of the Stored Procedure brought the time down from **17 minutes** to **40 seconds**.

Still far more than 1 second it takes to run in SSMS, and still not enough to be usable, but progress none the less.

However, I noticed that the Options value it returned (**5496**) was different to the value I got from the Execution Plan details above (**4345**), and also some of the settings where different from the settings for that database.

So, I re-ran the query hard-coded to 4345

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = 4345 --@@OPTIONS
PRINT @options
PRINT 'SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK ' + CASE WHEN ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ' + CASE WHEN ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT ' + CASE WHEN ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_WARNINGS ' + CASE WHEN ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_PADDING ' + CASE WHEN ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULLS ' + CASE WHEN ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ARITHABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ARITHIGNORE ' + CASE WHEN ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ' + CASE WHEN ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT ' + CASE WHEN ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ' + CASE WHEN ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF ' + CASE WHEN ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ' + CASE WHEN ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
PRINT 'SET XACT_ABORT ' + CASE WHEN ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END + ';'
```

This returned

```
4345
SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK ON;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET ARITHIGNORE ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON OFF;
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF OFF;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

Again, the line **SET DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK ON;** says it's not an option you can set, so I commented it out.

Updated the Stored Procedure with those SET values, and tried again.

It still takes 40 seconds, so no further progress.

Running it in SSMS still takes 1 second, so at least it didn't break that, not that it's any help but nice to know!

**Edit #2**: Or not...

Seems yesterday's apparent progress was a blip: it's back to taking 17 minutes again! (With nothing changed)

Tried combining all three options: WITH RECOMPILE, OPTION OPTIMIZE and explicitly setting the SET OPTIONS. Still takes 17 minutes.

**Edit 3**: **Parameter Sniffing Setting**

In SQL Azure, you can turn off Parameter Sniffing from the database options screen.

[image]

And check them using

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations
```

[image]

Tried SSMS and C# twice each after setting this to OFF.

As before, SSMS takes 1 second, C# still takes 15+ minutes.

Of course, given C# forces a load of parameters to a specific state when it connects, it's entirely possible that it's overriding it.

So, just to say I tried it, I added turning it off to the Stored Procedure

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = OFF;
```

Still 15+ minutes.

Ah well, was worth a try!

Plus, lots of new parameters to look up and test.

**Edit #4** : Azure Staging Pool Configurations and Automatic Tuning

I tried out several different configurations on the Staging Pool, to see if that made a difference. I didn't try the worst query, as it was costing us money to up the eDTUs, but I tried several others, twice each (going down the list each time, so not the same one twice straight away).

[image: Timing Tests]

Going from 50 eDTUs to 100 eDTUs made a bit of a difference, so I guess on our Test Elastic Pool we use all of the 50, but after that it didn't make any difference. Oddly, the Premium gave worse performance than Standard in places.

I then posted this on the Azure MSDN site (when they finally got round to Verifying my account), and they suggested going through all the Performance options on the Azure Portal and see if that recommends anything.

[image: Azure Performance Options]

It suggested a couple of indexes, which I enabled, but that was all.

Then I flipped the Automatic Tuning over from 'Server' to 'Azure Defaults'

[image: Azure Defaults]

I re-ran most of the same timing tests, just to see what difference it had made.

[image: Timing Tests After]

The query that had been taking 17 minutes now generally took 13 seconds, a massive improvement! Yay!

The rest were a mixed bag. C was generally quicker, most still took around the same time, and E now takes nearly twice as long (26s up from 14s).

There results also seemed to have a lot more variance than they did before, although it's possible that changing the eDTU size resets the tunings. The second run was usually better than the first, often noticeably so.

Still all a lot slower than running the same system against a database on a local server, but a huge improvement for the slowest Stored Procedure at least.

Comment: I am not sure if https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would not be a better place for this question...

Comment: `NOLOCK` is a bug to begin with. It doesn't mean `donb't take locks`. It means `read dirty data while taking excessive locks`. The very fact you tried to use that hint means you already have performance issues

Comment: You didn't post the queries or the execution plans so it's impossible to guess what's going on. The only certain thing is that there are some bad queries in that code. SSMS and your program (not C#, your program) will load different amounts of data, use different settings for ARITH_ABORT etc. Again though, you're asking people to guess. Is the difference caused because SSMS *won't* load everything? Maybe, maybe not. Is it because the Azure SQL instance is too small? Maybe, all those NOLOCKs hint at existing performance issues.

Comment: Another potential problem - does `@SEARCHTYPE` mean the same stored procedure executes different queries? Like catch-all queries, the problem may be that the first execution generates an execution plan inappropriate for  subsequent calls.

Comment: `The only differences are the localisation bits` those aren't *localization* bits. The collation does affect performance. It shouldn't matter when using dates and numbers though, those are binary values, unless they were stored as *strings* requiring parsing on every query. For string searches though, collation matters as *indexes* are built using the column's collation. If you try to change the query collation, you prevent the server from using any indexes. `the C# program forces it to British.` That could be the problem. Also, *why* does the program do that?

Comment: You've exhaustedly tried all options to solve a parameter sniffing problem.... but I still think it's a parameter sniffing problem. "Kitchen sink: stored procedures are very susceptible to them. What happens if you hard code the parameter values? Also check the server settings. Maybe one has MAXDOP set differently.

Comment: Does the stored procedure contain the execution of a dynamic request (with exec() or sp_executesql)?

Comment: Have you tried removing the left joins and then adding them back one at a time? Select only one field from the main table, and one field from each left join as you add them back. I had a similar problem and it turned out that some foreign keys were missing, which I only spotted when re-adding one table massively slowed performance.

Comment: Are you certain the C# code is the same? Can you use extended events in SQL to confirm the query is taking all this time? When you run the Azure proc from SSMS, does it take 1 second to return _all_ the rows? How many rows are returned?

Comment: Maybe your Azure Sql-Server ist far slower than your local machine? How many DTU's do you have configured in Azure? Do you hit your DTU limit in Azure?

Comment: @user743414 If I understand correctly, the OP is saying that using the same Azure database, the query runs quickly from SSMS but slowly from C#

Comment: If you look into CPU cores, your local machine have 8 cores and Azure have 1 core. Check other specs too, RAM etc. This could be the potential issue. You have to buy processing power.

Comment: I apologise that I haven't read that entire post, but it's worth noting that `with recompile` won't always help with parameter sniffing / cached plan issues. Use `option (recompile)` at the end of the statement(s) which are taking a long time to execute.

Comment: Very comprehensive post. Thanks for that.
As I was reading through, I thought adding `WITH RECOMPILE` would help, but as I read on was surprised to see it had no effect. Interesting that switching to Azure Defaults resulted in significantly faster results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out environmental issues? Check your allocation of memory, disk space, cpu, and network bandwidth for your azure server. SQL is a hog for both memory and disk space.

But you probably already checked all that. My next guess would be the connection string. You'll definitely need to use different syntax in the connection string for connecting to an Azure Sql instance as opposed to a local/network hosted one. See [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/) for details on the azure specific connection string syntax. (Remember that Azure Sql Server is different software than regular Sql Server. They try to look the same and pretend to behave the same, but they really are different under the hood.) It's possible that something like authentication or encryption is the bottleneck. Especially authentication is likely to be different between your SSMS connection and your code connection string.

Answer (score 0):

When SQL runs in 1 second in SSMS and 17 minutes in C#, check your connection settings.

The default SSMS connection settings are:

ANSI_NULLS

ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON

ANSI_PADDING

ANSI_WARNINGS

CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL

QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

**And all sample code on Microsoft websites are testing with these settings**

Code Example Conventions
Unless stated otherwise, the examples provided in the Transact-SQL Reference were tested by using SQL Server Management Studio and its default settings for the following options:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Here are samples of fixing issues using the connection settings

SQL Email ERROR: transaction not longer valid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/database-mail-fails-send-message

FIX: SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

SET ARITHABORT must be ON when you're creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If SET ARITHABORT is OFF, CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements on tables with indexes on computed columns or indexed views fail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -5):

When you call your SP from `C#` you should include the name of the database:

`[YourDatabaseName].[dbo].[usp_DevelopmentSearch_Select]`

In `SSMS`, your database will most likely be active. Hence, the server will know which database you are querying. When running on your local server, you most likely have very few databases (perhaps only one?). Hence, your local server will know which database you are querying.

But, in `Azure` you may very well have multiple databases, so it might need to scan through multiple databases. That will explain the delay you are seeing.

Comment: It doesn't. For starters, every query is against the connection's database. It's the *schema* that's often omitted, resulting in a search in all schemas. On-prem database servers have *far more* databases than hosted databases which, by design, prevent access to other people's databases. A simple search would never convert a 1s query to a 17 minute query either.

Comment: Is you test case from a cold start?  Has the database been used within the last minute or two before the C# application runs the stored procedure?

Azure is slow when the first query is executed as it has to star the SQL Server, mount the files, open the database, etc.